# Realm: the right way to make add,update,remove operations from background thread and get results on the main thread

Tags: ios, thread-safety, realm

I am using Realm for my app, i want to be able to query results on a background thread and receive them on the main thread. 
What is the best way to achieve this? and what is the best practice to use realm (having different method for main thread and background? and in main using a static instance of realm across the app? maybe another good way?)

I've read and saw this options are available:
- parsing the realm object to my own object and return them (kind of a copy of the results).
- returning a the key of the object and querying again from main thread.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me, i really think realm has great potential but there is a lack of good tutorials and best practices.

Answer (score 6):

First, since Realm is fast enough in most cases, you do not need to run a query in the background.

So the basic strategy is; update in background, fetch in the main thread.

The most general way is to take advantage of the feature of the live update.
`RLMResults` and `Results` have live update. You can hold `RLMResults`/`Results` instances by query. Then you'll make any changes in background thread, the changes are notified and reflected automatically when committed.

```
// Hold RLMResults for the data source
self.array = [[DemoObject allObjects] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"date" ascending:YES];
```

```
// Reload table view when changed by other threads
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.notification = [RLMRealm.defaultRealm addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, RLMRealm *realm) {
    [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // RLMResults is updated automatically
    return self.array.count;
}
```

```
// Update in background 
- (void)backgroundAdd
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    // Import many items in a background thread
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Get new realm and table since we are in a new thread
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
            // Add row via dictionary. Order is ignored.
            [DemoObject createInRealm:realm withValue:@{@"title": [self randomString],
                                                         @"date": [self randomDate]}];
        }
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
    });
}
```

For more details, you can see the [table view example in Realm's repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/TableView/TableViewController.m).

If a few cases that Realm doesn't fast enough when fetch on the main thread, you can fetch in background thread. Then aggregate an array of primary keys. Then pass the array and re-fetch on the main thread using the primary keys.

FYI: We are working to add support for running queries asynchronously https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2842
If this feature will be released, you don't need to aggregate primary keys and re-fetch.

Comment: what about parsing the realm objects into my own swift objects and than returning them? will it take longer the re-fetching? and another question, what about using realm on main thread, what is the best practice to get the realm instance? should i put a static instance in app delegate or somewhere else and than use this reference wherever i need or create realm reference in each place i want to get data?

Comment: What about updates? If I try to perform an update in a background thread using the objects I read in the main thread I get this exception: 'Can not add objects from a different Realm'

Comment: @Ixx You are misunderstanding how to use the Realm. Realm object cannot pass to other threads, also cannot add objects from a different Realm. You should create Realm instance on each thread and re-fetch Realm objects. However, Realm objects are live, up to date automatically. So best practice is querying on main thread, then writing background thread . Realm objects are live, you do not need to re-query.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't use the realm object in different threads, hence the question. More specifically, to perform an update should I 1. Create a new instance of the Realm object being updated, i.e. a copy? 2. Do the update in the main thread (same thread where I read the object), 3. Query the object again in the background to update it (inefficient)?

Comment: Addendum: I'm using a different Realm (i.e. instantiating a new one in the update background thread) but it crashes anyway. The problem are apparently the objects, which are the same loaded by read. Non-update saving, which uses the same code as updating works. Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: @Ixx Can you post your problem as a new question? It's hard to resolve/explain in comments.